# Shell Script Won't Run

Tags: permissions, scripts, files, filemanager

Newbie.  I am trying to install BeautifulSoup4.  There is a shell script "convert-py3k" to run, to convert to Python 3 version.  It has an executable permission but, neither double clicking nor, running it from the command line works. Says file not found. What am I not getting?

I tried it with a sudo and got the same results.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Running an executable file that exists in the same directory you are in, requires the use of **./** in the beginning of the filename.  In this case, the correct sytax to use in the terminal is:
`./convert-py3k` + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

There should be **NO spaces** between ./ and the filename.

Comment: I'm glad it worked.  Please mark the answer as accepted if you like.

Comment: shouldn't it search in the current directory automatically?  why do i have to include a path?

Comment: thought i marked the answer accepted.   why doesn't it run from the GUI?

Comment: Linux doesn't work that way.  If no path is defined, it searches inside the predefined path only.  The current folder is not included automatically.

Comment: There's a chance it did run from the gui but since it's not a gui app, its output needs an open terminal window for you to be able to see it.  So you need to create a launcher to run the script inside a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined the path variable in any of `.profile` or `.bashrc` file.

use `./` at the beginning of the file name without space as described in first answer. Or you can also run your script without `./` and from any directory.

For that, you'll have to add PATH variable in `.profile`. 
Best way is to make a directory and keep all your scripts in it and define the path of that directory to PATH variable in your `.profile` file.

You will be able to run all your scripts in this directory from any other directory and without using `./`.